# GAPI authentication via cookie on Firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-api, google-api-js-client

I'm hosting a project on Firebase, but I'm using `gapi.auth2` for authentication on the browser.  When Safari's tracking prevention feature is turned on, all `google.com` cookies are deleted at the end of the browsing session, which seem to be used by GAPI to store which user was logged in on my service.  The result is that when another browsing session is opened, the user has to log in again.  This does not happen if I turn off "Prevent cross-site tracking", nor is it a problem in Chrome, for example.

[image: Tracking preferences in Safari]

Is there a simple way to solve this problem?  Can I tell GAPI somehow to use my domain for its cookies?  It's hosted by Google, too, after all.  Anything else I can do?